# Return Values of Recursive Dynamic Variables in Batch

Tags: variables, dynamic, batch-file, return

I'm attempting to use dynamic variables within Delayed Variable Expansion to represent other Dynamic Variables. I'm running into some trouble. How can I get a dynamic variable's value's value if the dynamic variable's value is another dynamic variable with it's own value?

i.e. !valA! = %valB% = this

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
...
...
FOR /F ... %%G IN (...) DO (
    SET _temp=%%~nG
    SET _file=!_temp:~0,-4!
    SET _cnt=0
    FOR /F ... %%L IN (...) DO (
        SET _temp=%%L
        SET _str=!_temp:*: =!
        SET /A _cnt+=1
        SET _temp=x!_file!!_cnt!
        IF DEFINED !_temp! (
            SET _temp=!%_temp%!
::
::_temp('s value) is _var('s value) is "xyz"
::Set new _temp to equal current _temp's "xyz"
::
            IF !_temp! NEQ !_str! (
                ECHO File Content Mismatch
            )
        ) ELSE (
            SET xvar=!_temp!
            SET !xvar!=!_str!
        )

    )
)
...
...
exit
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Woot! PhD grade batch scripting. I thought everybody had wised up and went with PowerShell these days

Comment: I am curious about the line: "SET _temp=!%_temp%!". Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Arun reassign _temp to the current _temp(which is a variable name) value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically your failing code equates to

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(
  set VAR1=success
  set VAR2=VAR1
  set VAR3=!%VAR2%!
  echo VAR3=!VAR3!
)
```

As has already been pointed out in previous answers and comments, you can't assign a value to VAR2 and then access the value using %VAR2% within the same code block because %VAR2% is expanded during the parsing phase of the code block, at which point the value is not what you want (probably undefined).

But you need a second level of expansion in addition to !VAR2! to get the result you want. I know of three solutions.

**1)** This solution works, but it is not recommended because it is slow.

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(
  set VAR1=success
  set VAR2=VAR1
  call set VAR3=%%!VAR2!%%
  echo VAR3=!VAR3!
)
```

Prior to the execution of the CALL, each %% is reduced to %, and !VAR2! becomes VAR1.
Thus the called statement becomes `set VAR3=%VAR1%`, and the called statement is reparsed through the %var% expansion phase, so you get your desired result.

BUT - CALL is relatively very expensive. When used in a loop it can cause severe performance degradation. jeb provides a good demonstration and explanation at [CALL me, or better avoid call](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1947&p=8386#p8386)

**1a)** There is a variation of the CALL solution where you call a :LABELed subroutine. Because the subroutine is parsed after the call, you can simply use `set VAR3=!%VAR2%!`. But again, this uses CALL so it is relatively slow and not recommended.

**2)** This general solution works, and is *MUCH* faster in comparison. It uses a FOR variable for the second level of expansion. This is the recommended solution.

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(
  set VAR1=success
  set VAR2=VAR1
  for /f %%A in ("!VAR2!") do set VAR3=!%%A!
  echo VAR3=!VAR3!
)
```

**3)** If the value of VAR1 is known to be an integer, then there is a special case solution using `SET /A`

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(
  set VAR1=999
  set VAR2=VAR1
  set /a VAR3=!VAR2!
  echo VAR3=!VAR3!
)
```

The SET /A command has its own built in expansion of variables that takes place after delayed expansion, and no punctuation is needed.

Comment: I ended up solving it another way, but I have forgotten what it was because I since quit that job.

Comment: I think I lied after re-reading this. I am not sure, but I _think_ I went with something along the lines of your #2 @dbenham. I remember it took me a few days to mull over and get it working. I'm going to try to get ahold of some of the old scripts so I can see what it was that I actually did. Thanks for the help so long ago. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails at `SET _temp=!%_temp%!`, as the percent expansion is evaluated while parsing the parenthesis block.

You could change it to

```
set "varname=!_temp!"
set "content=!varname!"
```

Btw. It would be much easier, if your sample would be reduced to the minimum of code, like.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "var1=content of var1"
set "var2=var1"
set "result=!%var2%!"
echo !result!
```

This only works as it isn't in brackets.

To better understand how the different expansions work,
you can read [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts/4095133#4095133)

Comment: The code block is parsed from a larger block of code that does not play well with others when using calls to other functions. C'est la vie. Cheers.